# Only accept a float between 0 and 1 - python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, floating-point

So I need a really efficient code which will accept any number between 0 and 1 from the user and keep on prompting them to try again until their input meets this criteria.
This is what I've got so far:

```py
def user_input():
    while True:
        global initial_input
        initial_input = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 0")
        if initial_input.isnumeric() and (0 <= float(initial_input) <= 1):
            initial_input = float(initial_input)
            return(initial_input)
        print("Please try again, it must be a number between 0 and 1")

user_input()
```

This works but only if the number is actually 1 or 0. If you input a decimal between these (e.g 0.6), it crashes

Comment: *If you input a decimal between these (e.g 0.6), it crashes*.... what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message apart from "Unresolved attribute reference 'is numeric' for class 'float'". The loop just runs as if I input a number that is not in-between 1 and 0 (Keeps asking me to try again) @Xoce

Comment: You're converting the input to float twice, once *before* you try calling a string method on it. Look at your code line-by-line until you understand what each one is doing.

Comment: So do you know how to fix it? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Yes, but I think you should work it out for yourself.

Comment: you need raw_input for python2 but that is still going to fail,  `"0.5".isnumeric() -> False`, your errors also do not add up as `1.isnumeric() ` would also error just as `some_float.isnumeric()` would . Just use a try/except.

Comment: Yeah I've tried but I don't really understand it. Please could you point me in the right direction. @jonrsharpe

Comment: 1- the error message suggests that you are running Python 2, not Python 3. Put the error message into your question (move it from the comments). The question text should be enough, to answer it without reading all the comments. 2- `isnumeric()` won't work for a float str such as `"0.1"`. It won't work even for `int()` (it is too general). `isdecimal()` may work for integers 3- [use `float()` to extract floats and catch `ValueError`. You can compare its performance with the regex from the link.](http://goo.gl/w4KFAF) 4- You don't need "really efficient code"  here -- humans type very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a try/except returning the input only if it is a number between 0 and 1, catching bad input as a ValueError:

```
def user_input():
    while True:
        try:
            # cast to float
            initial_input = float(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 0"))      # check it is in the correct range and is so return 
            if 0 <= initial_input <= 1:
                return (initial_input)
            # else tell user they are not in the correct range
            print("Please try again, it must be a number between 0 and 1")
        except ValueError:
            # got something that could not be cast to a float
            print("Input must be numeric.")
```

Also if you get  `"Unresolved attribute reference 'is numeric' for class 'float'".` using your own code then you are using python2 not python3 as you only cast after the *isnumeric* check so that means the input is eval'd.  If this is the case use *raw_input* in place of *input*.

Answer (score -1):

You first need to check if it really is a float, `if "." in initial_input`, and then you can go on to the other conversions:

```
def user_input():
    while True:    
        initial_input = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 0").strip()
        if "." in initial_input or initial_input.isnumeric():
            initial_input = float(initial_input)
            if 0 <= initial_input <= 1:
                print("Thank you.")
                return initial_input
            else:
                print("Please try again, it must be a number between 0 and 1")
        else:
            # Input was not an int or a float
            print("Input MUST be a number!")

initial_input = user_input()
```